# How Do I can do a live streaming of JPG imagens?

Tags: camera

I saw you talking about making videos with jpgs in linux, How can I do a live streaming from videos sent by a security cam?

The cam just send jpgs by ftp even 1seg.

Comment: Hi, Daniel, you're probably still getting to know how Stack Exchange works. We don't know who is "you"... Can you link to the question that talks about "making videos with jpgs in linux"? Do you already have any live stream solution? Please, [edit] your question and add more details.

Comment: brasofilo is right. Might be a good idea to add more context in oder to get a solid answer. For creating a video by an image sequence via ffmpeg, see: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/7903/how-to-losslessly-encode-a-jpg-image-sequence-to-a-video-in-ffmpeg